# How do you print \ in python

Tags: python, string

I would like to print a backslash character:

```
\
```

But whne I try to use escape characters

```
print(\"\"\)
```

I get a syntax error. I have looked into ecape characters, however is their a specific one for backslash ()?

Comment: Try print('\\')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do

```
print("\")
```

you are escaping the final quote.

You need to escape the backslash.

```
print("\\")
```

Answer (score 1):

It is simple, just escape the escape character itself:

```py
print("\\")
```